# how to output the quantity for a certain month according to the condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to withdraw all concluded employment contracts for a month and if a legal entity has concluded an employment contract, then its number is doubled
the problem is that my query groups it incorrectly
Btw i have to do that with cursor

```
    DECLARE @month VARCHAR(10) 
    DECLARE @count INT
    DECLARE cursorTest CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Z1.month, (COUNT(*) * z1.count) AS count
    FROM (Select month([rental_start_date]) as month, 
        case 
            when
                (t.tenant_code in (Select [tenant_code] from [dbo].[Legal_entities] ))
                then 2
            when 
                (t.tenant_code in (Select [tenant_code] from [dbo].[Individuals] ))
                then 1
            end as count
                from [dbo].[lease_agreements] l 
                    inner join [dbo].[Tenants] t on l.tenant_code=t.tenant_code
                        inner join [dbo].[Real_estate] r on l.number_of_object = r.number_of_object
                WHERE
                    r.total_area < 30 or r.total_area 
                        BETWEEN 30 AND 50 
                        AND 
                        (DATEDIFF(month, l.rental_start_date, l.rental_end_date) > 1)
                        AND
                        (DATEDIFF(MONTH,l.rental_start_date, l.rental_end_date) % 3 = 0)
    ) AS Z1
    group by Z1.month,z1.count
    OPEN cursorTest
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorTest INTO @month,@count
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Month: ' + @month + ', Count: ' + CAST((@count) AS VARCHAR(10))
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorTest INTO @month,@count
    END 
    CLOSE cursorTest DEALLOCATE cursorTest
```

Result has to be:
Month 1, Count 3
Month 2 Count 3
etc

[image]

Comment: FYI, a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Comment: I know the problem is with groub by, but without it the query won't work

Comment: But why is the `DISTINCT` there, when your `GROUP BY` is already forcing your data to be returned in *distinct sets*?

Comment: Where does `z1.Количество` (it's probably in Bulgarian) come from? And what do you want to calculate with `COUNT(*) * z1.Количество`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to work out as you have supplied no sample data but from what I can understand the problem is the inner query.

The cursor is probably not required either if you just want to output the same data as the messages you have shown.

This might not be correct, as I said, tricky to fix when I don't know if I understand the problem but try this..

```
SELECT 
        MONTH(rental_start_date) AS [Month], 
        SUM(
            CASE WHEN le.tenant_code IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 2 END +
            CASE WHEN  i.tenant_code IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            ) AS Quantity
    FROM lease_agreements l
        JOIN Tenants t on l.tenant_code=t.tenant_code
            JOIN Real_estate r on l.number_of_object = r.number_of_object
        LEFT JOIN Legal_entities le on t.tenant_code = le.tenant_code
        LEFT JOIN Individuals i on t.tenant_code = i.tenant_code
    WHERE
        r.total_area < 30 
        OR r.total_area BETWEEN 30 AND 50 
        AND (DATEDIFF(month, l.rental_start_date, l.rental_end_date) > 1)
        AND (DATEDIFF(MONTH,l.rental_start_date, l.rental_end_date) % 3 = 0)
    GROUP BY MONTH(rental_start_date)
```

If the above gives you the correct data then you could easily wrap that in another query to give the final output, something like this..

```
SELECT 
    'Month: ' + CAST(a.Month as varchar(10)) + ', Count: ' + CAST(a.Quantity as varchar(10))
    FROM (
          [copy query from above here]
         ) a
```

Comment: Your request works perfectly, thank you!